# Font type changes after using the command dvipdf dummy.dvi

Tags: fonts, dvipdf

When I try to change my document type from dvi to pdf, font type changes. To show this change, hereby I put two pictures from the dvi and pdf files, respectively.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I use this preamble in my document:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}  
\usepackage{OkanFBEStyle}  
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage{subfigure}  
\usepackage{srcltx}  
\usepackage{boxedminipage}  
\usepackage{enumerate}  
\usepackage{cite}  
\usepackage{wrapfig}  
%\usepackage{natbib}  
%\usepackage{FBEbib}  
\pdfminorversion=5  
%  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  
%  \usepackage{winfonts}  
%      \usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
```

There are more packages, however I could not type here because of the letter constraint. I hope this information is enough to identify the problem. Can anybody help me on this please?

Comment: i don't think there's enough here for anyone to work on.  please give us a concrete example (preferably a minimal source file) and explain what you mean by "font type changes".

Comment: The information has been updated wasteofspace.

Comment: It's difficult to say something, since the `OkanFBEStyle` is unknown. However you should avoid `srcltx`, which is obsolete; can't you use `pdflatex` directly?

Comment: @egreg I removed srcltx package in your advice. I can not use pdflatex as I have eps files. However, I can put here my style file if anyone want to look at it. Thanks.

Comment: @RızaBayoğlu If you have a recent TeX Live, then you can convert EPS files to PDF on the fly.

Comment: @egreg Can you lead me how to do that please? I am not sure if that will gonna solve the problem.

Comment: Simply put `\usepackage{epstopdf} in your document and try to compile with pdflatex. But it will probably not solve your font problem. For this run a small example with some text with pdflatex, then show us the list of fonts at the end of the log-file (files with extension `.pfb` or `.pk` normally).

Comment: @egreg I run again following your suggestion. However, it did not compile using pdflatex. I checked that epstopdf package was already installed in my computer. But, it did not compile somehow. It says:  dummy.tex:123: No destination for bookmark of \addcontents line, (hyperref) destination is added in input line 123.  dummy.tex:159:  Token not allowed in a Pdf string, (PDFDocenconding), (hyperref), \kern....

Comment: @egreg I checked the dummy.log file and could not find any .pfb or .pk files in the document. But, only this:  LaTeX Font Info: Try loading font information for T1+cmtt on input line 200.

(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/t1cmtt.fd
File: t1cmtt.fd 1999/05/25 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
and this one: **This may be the reason for font change**!   
! pdfTeX error (font expansion): auto expansion is only possible with scalable 
fonts.
\AtBegShi@Output ...ipout \box \AtBeginShipoutBox 
                                                  \fi \fi 
l.1 \begin{thebibliography}{1}

Comment: @egreg I can send you the log file if you need it.

Comment: @RızaBayoğlu That error message comes from the package `microtype` which really modifies the font (in a good and sensitive way), and is compatible only with PdfLaTeX.

Comment: @tohecz I removed that package, and saw that it is not the one to cause font change.

Answer (score 2):

This error is caused by `microtype` package. This package is compatible only with pdfLaTeX (and partially with XeLaTeX and LuaTeX), but not with anything that uses `dvi` format. However, the output of `dvi->png` and `dvi->pdf` conversion can differ, since the `microtype` instructions can be used in the resulting `pdf` but the measurements can be wrong.

Conclusion: Never use `microtype` with `dvi`.

Comment: I updated my preamble adding:         \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}       \usepackage{epstopdf}                                   and removed this:                        \usepackage{microtype}                                            Then, with _pdflatex_ I got the third picture in the original question. Comparing pictures 1 & 3, the third one is a bit different than first one (smaller and darker font). I suspect that this difference might come from the _microtype_ . Therefore, I added this and recompile, it did not compile saying that fatal error occured. What do you suggest at this point?

Comment: If the question is only the darkness of the font, try printing both, I think that they would be much more similar. The difference in display versions is due to different anti-aliasing methods used by different programs and formats.

Comment: Yes, it is exactly. After printing the document I realized that there is no font change with the prints, but with the pdf file. Thanks.